# Some hats are gone from the leaderboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

Some hats are missing from the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

[image]

[image]

They are all secret hats, but not all secret hats are missing - I see a few Time Lord hats around too. Reproduced in Chrome and Firefox (beta channel). They were working fine yesterday, I believe.

Examining the page in the developer tools, there's some JS that's coming back as  404, with oddities in the URL.

[image]

Comment: can you post the leader board link

Comment: yaa same here on windows 7 chrome and I think they are top secret!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed, thanks. That `undefined` was supposed to be the location of all static assets, which wasn't initialized correctly.